# Typescript: Having problems with very complex generic type mapping of records

Tags: typescript

Uff... Spend a whole working day on this. My brain is melting...

I am writing a type-safe mapper-function which knows which props are required depending on the mapping-type and can infer the output types depending from the ReturnType.
But apparently it doesn't apply my type mapping individually for each record but for all values at once, resulting in an intersection type of all possible items instead of the individual ones.

It's really hard to explain, so here is what I got so far:

[working example in typescriptlang.org playground here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAggxsAlgewHYGE3AIaNRAJwB4AlARgBooSAmKgBTKggA9gJUATAZym1RABtALoMazNhx58BIgHxQAvFADeAWABQUKKmwBbCAC4o3YATwBzANybtZ-twBmyAnuMAKAHTfsBC92NGAEolBXIbLSgCCAA3QmAPb09ff0CaEMUwmgiAXwjNRwBXVAQUVD5StAAhQsQAG05CIlsoADEmVnYuXi8fPwCZEAyFfhAKFtbxTqkezmwcY3JhwfHI8gku6RIIYEKCVAAVcAgidrlV7VoNmeodvcPj05pzlsZr7qh6X30dwm5TsgvSL0KaSD5fAg-dgEf6TOSaOTuXQGYymcyoCxUeyoJwuNxQXrJfqBMjLchUaJxAgJAlzBbUUmhajpYzwJBoTCoHB4Jrk5kMSifZ6qFrRXb7EWRbTIiAXbRQbG41xy7SU%20JyvKaHKaTSsMAuYBQOBoUxQOkQEj8CzQZTYSqoGr1RoEdwtADk5stGIgbrl7kcBGQ%20LRlixyFRZksQWMABF5hAREz1FKoncJSIItocn66dhY-GRNHbsaCJwiCGMVQKxYFJlJfLU%20LyiooAGg8Y3WRfQrw1A3TQ3VBNZFtRogvkNHqDUaTYb2KbbfbHQ1CK7Im758BfS1-YgIA0I%20iLEXq0mWqq0%20UNxBTGQAIRuzNDv2OPcHkyRjEnz8WM8psX3H2m5MGq1IQJwD5PqO446hooCQLA9pEActYtAAPvWDY6D8HaelaPpPg28EQAA-MYxHII4Zrxl61qEfKbb4gc9F2L2zHnkO6GYQ2Modpuj4cXYxxkQqxyUQqN7ACxrZvpwxjsSmw6aMRsCcGWADS7zSNWVAAGpabwbJlEQoxyLWxYuBpekGaoomQCJLaKs4riJH0qSDMseCOIQUAAKLiDkQ5QCRfniMY%20BUnIE5TtSZoQI42CFHUhpFCU7LlIU3AQAckI4s5BjEAAkgAclQvk2QA1hAIDiSVVDFTZOlQAAsjZ2wlmWpWIelRC%20WZiKmPGxh1VAejYGAYCWAM7WWUQXVGWgvVmSEyZCQhrR4kcCHKAA8noiDAEQI19VAABkqmdViYlUWNE1TYIxXCFFUAAPQvVAADqAASACaUCFQAyqN42TRi3APcIOjIIaxpcIgzrgVAeCcIgMTw4U2B1HUICti4zB2gAFlAxUhYVhpZRAei8MABPzEjhqZTefBY1A%20rcNwiAAEbY1AMSY4UTPibdoP%20EkoqXtxuMuaogXYLwG2uFtsotMOo7KccsBKJheYfkeT7mq0gbBj%20%20vxgcvbVk%20nOHpYT5wOFhR6JzhC5BOsOmtgrT1HU4GslrLY626zjIN2BtGx2NAAAw0GQAC0kcAGzxzQBw0DQhiR5HGeR54meRwAWqHZu9v20dx4nyep%20nmfZ7nmeF1Q1t9pzvjdvbUBkDQADMQ5u7Otn5UFyiMzlDj5aunve%20BVCrVhuXWsYLa8X2eHet2jG4fGhtBt2wAl%20a5uDtmgkmIgehgD7zXjYv2EokBknr7JHbYEfKpDjBGiaO7c6SUwyj5Z4OAVhXrvVQI7Z2BBjAAHcXAVW4F-fum5xD-zxJ4eeEBgFvRMATZASVOBQGdlAOM7BEzuE5oUQ0iBeCngwsQhMwgggIJxD-UwPcUGuE8Bzc%20l9xqYPetwHBeCCHQFPGQihSNqE-igLQgsDDNBAA)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! The way SO works, your whole question (including any necessary code) has to be **in** your question, not just linked. (The link is a good *addition*, though!) Three reasons: People shouldn't have to go off-site to help you; some sites are blocked for some users; and links rot, making the question and its answers useless to people in the future. Please put a [mcve] **in** the question. More: [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: *(I'd do it for you, but I can't grant Stack Overflow the necessary license to your code.)*

Comment: @T.J.Crowder huh, it never occurred to me that there might be licensing issues surrounding copying someone's plaintext code into the question.  In this case the info is encoded into the URL itself, so copying it is presumably just "rephrasing" something that's already on SO.  But if it were a link to something where the content is external (codesandbox, etc) then I guess that's not true.  Is there some meta answer somewhere about this issue? (My searches are drowned out by results on copying code *from* SO.)  I don't want to break rules if I can help it.

Comment: @jcalz - Yeah, I did think about the fact it's encoded in the URL but decided that I can't be sure the OP knew that. :-) [This answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/344512/157247) seems to be the one that people get pointed to. It's one of those things...you know it's okay, 99.9999% of the time, but... (Also doing it oneself is perhaps useful in terms of knowing to do it next time, but that's a bit passive aggressive. :-) )

Comment: Thanks!  I'll refer to that answer in the future for such issues.

Comment: Patrick, as you can see, Stack Overflow is a **very** busy place. :-) When you post a question (or answer!), please stick around for a few minutes so you can respond to anything that comes up in the comments. @jcalz is an absolute TypeScript wizard, I'd love to see their answer to what you've described above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Took some finicking and trial-and-error, but I got something that seems to work *partially*:

```
type ActionResult<A extends Action<any>['name']> = { [action in Action<any> as A]: action extends { name: A, type?: { transform: (...args: any) => infer R } } ? R : never; }[A];

export default function useTransformer<IN, E extends keyof IN, M extends Record<keyof M, Action<E>>>(state: IN, mappings: M) {
  type N = keyof M;
  return {
    form: {} as {
      [K in E | N]: K extends N ? ActionResult<M[K]['name']> : (K extends keyof IN ? IN[K] : never);
    },
  };
}

// Results in form to be of type:
const form: {
    range: Date[];
    dateFrom: string;
    dateTo: string;
    simpleMap: string;
    a: string;
    b: string;
    c: number;
};
```

Two small (intertwined) problems: it doesn't omit fields used in transformers, and the `E` generic type is "useless" (because I'd use to omit the fields, but TS can't narrow it enough).

You can fix the first problem (and therefore the 2nd) by creating a type like `ActionConsumes` to "calculate" which fields are consumed, e.g. something like:

```
interface ActionConsumesFields {
    dateRange: 'from' | 'to';
    test: 'field';
}
type ActionConsumes<A extends Action<any>> = {
  [name in keyof ActionConsumesFields]:
    A extends { name: name } & { [key in ActionConsumesFields[name]]: any } ? A[ActionConsumesFields[name]] : never }[keyof ActionConsumesFields];

export default function useTransformer<IN, E extends keyof IN, M extends Record<keyof M, Action<E>>>(state: IN, mappings: M) {
  type N = keyof M;
  type Consumed = ActionConsumes<M[keyof M]>;
  return {
    form: {} as {
      [K in Exclude<E, Consumed> | N]: K extends N ? ActionResult<M[K]['name']> : (K extends keyof IN ? IN[K] : never);
    },
  };
}

// Resulting type of form
// (notice how the dateFrom/dateTo/a fields are missing)
const form: {
    range: Date[];
    simpleMap: string;
    b: string;
    c: number;
};
```

*(see addition of the `ActionConsumes` stuff)*

Give me a few minutes and I might figure out in tricking TS to auto-calculate `ActionConsumerFields`, but no promises there.

---

Actually got the "auto-detect fields" to work:

```
const _ACS = Symbol();
type ActionConsumesFields = {
  [action in Action<typeof _ACS> as action['name']]: keyof { [key in keyof action as action[key] extends typeof _ACS ? key : never]: 1; };
};

// Resulting type of ActionConsumesFields:
type ActionConsumesFields = {
    dateRange: "from" | "to";
    test: "field";
};
```

Comment: Please see [this meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/344512/157247) and the discussion under this question.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Ah I see. Does it really matter if the only originally remaining code is the heavily edited `useTransformer`? While the function signature is very similar, everything else is completely different, so I think that technically I own the code (and therefore can grant a license to SO). _but I'm no lawyer._

Comment: Although to be fair my `Action` and `form` (and I now notice part of `ActionResult`) refer to OP's code, so maybe it's a bit more of a gray zone than I thought.

Comment: If it's really that little, I'd think it would be fair use (that and there's jcalz's point that the code technical *is* in the question, just encoded in the URL), but I'm not a lawyer either. :-) In general it seems like it's best to wait to answer a question until the question is sufficiently complete here on-site, but I can totally see arguments the other way. :-)

Comment: I got [this](https://tsplay.dev/m3zX1N) from my noodling with it; it really looks like this question is kind of low-effort, unfortunately.

Comment: That's a lot cleaner than my attempt, I like it. I had quite some fun with the weird mappings. And yes, too bad this question probably won't get much attention, it's actually quite interesting if you dive into it.

Comment: ok...Seriously thank you! For taking time to read this and actually solving that, what really gave me a headache because I couldn't figure out how to do it.
I am still not there to fully understand the solutions, but wow... I am so impressed by you guys. @jcalz

Comment: Both solutions are breaking some other part though :\  The intention is, that depending on `name: 'dateRange'` the possible fields are limited to the type (in this case only `from` and `to` are allowed). That worked in my example but is now gone, and any parameters are available. Reverting this seems to break the other validation. Not sure if they can co-exist at all?